# Access denied when starting HttpListener in a Windows Docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core

When I start an HttpListener in a .NET Core 2.1 console application running in a Windows Docker container I get this exception:

> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied

This is my code:

```
HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();
httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/test/");
httpListener.Start();
```

My Docker image is based on this Microsoft image:

> FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime

When I run my console application outside a Docker container it works if I start the application from a command prompt with Administrator rights. If I run it as a normal user outside a container it fails with the same Access Denied exception.

How can I avoid this exception when running in a Docker container? I don't think you can run a container as an Administrator.
I have seen suggestions to call this command

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:8080/ user=Everyone listen=yes
```

but the netsh command in the container does not have the http option.

Note: If I run the same program based on .NET Framework 4.7.2 in a container it works.

Looking for advice on this.

Comment: What’s the difference between these two running container beside FROM image?

Comment: There is no difference between the code running on .NET Core 2.1 and .NET framework 4.7.2. The project files just reference different .NET platfoms.

Comment: And you have problem with .NET framework 4.7.2, or u wanna figure out what’s going on with .NET Core2.1?

Comment: I am asking for help on how to run the 3 lines of code in a .NET Core 2.1 console application in a Docker container running on Windows without getting an Access Denied exception.

Comment: If I switch to Linux containers the program runs fine.